# Delay between losing health

Tags: python, pygame

I've recently implemented a health system (albeit a very basic one) into my game and it works in the sense that if my player is colliding with the enemy, I lose health. However, the problem that I'm facing is that I lose health 60 times a second as long as i stay in contact with the enemy.

What I actually want is this: every time the player collides with an enemy, it loses a chunk of health, but can't lose any more health until at least one second has passed. I've tried using time.sleep but that just seems to freeze the entire program instead of just the health system. Here is my code;

## Main Game

```
import pygame
from constants import *
from player import Player
from enemy import Enemy
import time


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])

pygame.display.set_caption('Labyrinth')

# Spawn player

player = Player(50, 50)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(player)


# Spawn enemy

enemy = Enemy(150, 150)
enemy_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_sprites.add(enemy)



clock = pygame.time.Clock()

done = False


# ----- Event Loop

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)


# ----- Game Logic

    all_sprites_list.update()
    enemy_sprites.update(player)

    player_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy_sprites, False)

    for hit in player_hit_list:
       player.health -= 10
       time.sleep(1)
       if player.health <= 0:
           done = True



    screen.fill(WHITE)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    enemy_sprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

## Player class

```
from constants import *
import pygame

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    def __init__(self, x, y):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.health = 10


        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
```

## Enemy Class

```
from constants import *
import pygame

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    def __init__(self, x, y):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 10])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```

(constants file just defines the colours black, red and white)

Any help at all would be immensely appreciated!

Comment: This is definitely doable (as Matthew Horst’s answer shows), but is the problem you’re trying to solve that losing 10 hp per frame, or even 1, is just too deadly? What if you just used float values for health and lost 1/6 hp per frame? Anyway, it’s definitely a different gameplay experience, and you may have a good reason for wanting this one; I just wanted to make sure you know both choices are easy, so you can pick whichever feels right for your game rather than whichever one you know how to implement.

Comment: In the example I just gave, i was just using some placeholder values. In my final product I aim to have a health bar where every hit takes away half of a heart, and you have x amount of hearts as seen in other games such as binding of isaac etc. I can imagine it being an incredibly difficult game if players died as quickly as they do in the example!

Comment: Sure, but you can take away 1/120th of a heart every 1/60th of a second. And you can "round it off" to the nearest half-heart for display. The difficulty wouldn't be any worse than taking away 1/2 of a heart every 1 second. Again, both designs are reasonable; you can find arcade (and retro) games that do it both ways, so if you chose your design for game-design reasons rather than what seems easiest to implement, that's great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a game developer so I don't know common patterns or anything, but a few ideas I have:

1. What if you set an `invincible_until` time on player, when they first lose health. You set it to 1 second beyond `now()`. Then you can keep hit checking as you do, but only actually subtract more health if the new `now()` is beyond the player's `invincible_until`. And of course when that happens, reset `invincible_until` again to another 1 second in the future.
2. What about if you save the "hit time", which is when the "hit" first occurred. Then while that hit is still true, only apply another loss of health if it's been more than 1 second past the "hit time". And of course at that same time, reset "hit time".

As @abarnert points out, my code isn't really "game"-y, I totally get that point about using frames. But I'll write the example in a way I'm more familiar with using datetimes and thinking from an object-oriented perspective. You could rework it to be based on frames for sure if you like. If you'd want to it that way, I imagine you'd use something like pygame's `get_time()` which uses milliseconds, and adding a second to that would just be `+ 1000`.

And of course you'd probably want to put the values like "1 second" in constants.

I just wrote code in-line here, I didn't run it, but I think I got the syntax and logic right. If not please feel free to edit, I think this should give you the sense of what I meant either way.

For example, #1 could be like this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        super().__init__()
        self.invincible_until = datetime.now()
        ...

    def _can_take_damage(self):
        if datetime.now() < self.invincible_until:
            return False

        return True

    def hit_check(self, damage):
        """Player is hit with potential damage of `damage`"""
        if self._can_take_damage():
            self.health -= damage
            self.invincible_until = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=1)

    def is_dead(self):
        return self.health <= 0

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
```

Then in game logic:

```
for hit in player_hit_list:
       player.hit_check(10)
       if player.is_dead():
           done = True
```

Comment: Great solutions. In an old-school arcade game, you’d likely do this by frame count instead of by time, and a PyGame game built on a frame loop is the same design as that old-school game. But, on the other hand, Python on a 3GHz Core processor has a whole lot more resources than assembly on a 1MHz Z80, so if using `datetime` objects is easier to understand, why not?

Comment: On paper this does make a lot of sense, but like you I am not a game developer, I've been slowly picking up the pieces of python as I add more elements to my game. Is it possible to be a bit more detailed in your answer? I'm not familiar with using timings and thus am not sure how to set `invincible_until` to 1 second beyond `now()` or how to reset `invincible_until` after this happens.

Comment: @Goose_ Updated post with example implementation.